# visual basic webbrowser navigate but password has a @ sign in p@ssword

Tags: vba, http-headers

the following code works with a normal password

```
  WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://username:Password@160.30.90.52/cgi-bin/statuspage.cgi ")
```

but my default password is p@ssword

```
  WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://username:P@ssword@160.30.90.52/cgi-bin/statuspage.cgi ")
```

how can i let this code run with the @ sign

i need to download files from a url programtically and all my code works all i still need is a way to pass the username and password to the url but the url password contaains that @ sign

Answer (score 0):

HI so it took a wile but finally found a answer
if you were to pass a username or password with certain special symbols like the @ sign you need to do some Encoding on the symbols 
instead of using p@ssword i now used p%40ssword and it worked heres my working code

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(" https://username:p%40ssword@160.30.90.52/cgi-bin/statuspage.cgi ")
```

and here are some other symbols you guys might need in the future

```
!  %21
[space] %20
@   %40
$   %24
%   %25
^   %5E
&   %26
*   %2A
(   %28
)   %29
?   %3F
,   %2C
=   %3D
```